# Are there any browser layout engines which interpret SASS natively (without CSS) or plugins which enable this?

Tags: html, css, browser, sass

Imagine a site made of just of HTML + SASS files, but displaying in a browser just like HTML + CSS. Essentially, skipping the step of compiling the SASS to CSS first. Is there any (even fringe) project that enables this?

Comment: Sass is designed to be compiled on the server side first before being handed out as CSS. How is such a browser going to tell the server that it can interpret the Sass file directly without it having to compile?

Comment: what would be the benefit? Why burden each individual end user with pre-processing when that can all be handled once on the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but there is work being done to move ideas from Sass/Less into standardized CSS. Contrary to the comments above, there are very good reasons to do the calculation on the client side. Browsers would be able to access the actual DOM, to do more informed calculations. Need to add percentages to pixels? Pre-processors can't do that, but a browser could.

In fact, that's the reason you don't want Sass to be implemented in a browser directly. Sass is awesome, but if browsers are implementing similar features, they should take those ideas even further by integrating with the DOM. That's happening now with [variables](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-variables/) and simple [calculations](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc-notation). Can't wait for more!

Comment: I'm not saying it's bad to do the calculations on the client side. It's just, Sass wasn't built for the client side. Personally I can't wait to see custom properties (ugh, variables) and new values/functions either.

Comment: Sass's end result is CSS, what the browser natively uses, so there'd be no reason to push the pre-processed code client-side only to have it turn into client side CSS. Now CSS, itself, makes perfect sense on the client-side, and the new features are definitely welcome.

Comment: oh man... how i've longed to be able to add percentages and pixels

Comment: Depending what browsers you need to support, you can start using it now. Support is now around 70%: http://caniuse.com/#search=calc