# User profile error

Tags: css, sass, jsfiddle

For some reason the css is not working I'm not sure where the problem is:

This is how it's supposed to look:

http://codepen.io/lukepeters/pen/DtzvE

The JS FIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/Wc3RK/

I don't know what went wrong? The code is the same but it's coming out differen't on the JS Fiddle.

CSS:

```
html 
height: 100%
body
height: 100%
//background: #a7d5cd
+background-image(linear-gradient(#dddddd, #cccccc))

#people
position: relative
margin: 80px auto
padding: 0
width: 480px
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif
font-size: 16px
line-height: 22px
color: #3b3b3b
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased
list-style-type: none

li
position: relative
margin: 0 0 40px 0
padding: 10px 8px 8px 54px
height: 42px
border: 1px solid #bbbbbb
border-radius: 4px
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.06), inset 0 1px 0 #ffffff
background: #f6f6f6

img
  position: absolute
  top: -16px
  left: -16px
  z-index: 10
  margin: 0
  padding: 4px
  width: 50px
  height: 50px
  border: 1px solid #bbbbbb
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ffffff
  border-radius: 50%
  background: #ffffff

h2
  margin: 0
  font-size: 18px
  line-height: 22px
  font-weight: 400
  color: #4b4b4b
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.7)

.info
  margin: 0
  display: block

  em
    margin: 0 18px 0 0
    font-size: 11px
    line-height: 20px
    font-weight: 400
    font-style: normal
    letter-spacing: 1px
    text-transform: uppercase
    color: #5b5b5b
    float: left
```

Comment: It's because jsfiddle doesn't have support for SASS.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about jsfiddle features.

Comment: Juhanna its not offtopic. If he had pasted the same thing into a webpage, he'd get the same result. It was because of sass, not jsfiddle

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any browser layout engines which interpret SASS natively (without CSS) or plugins which enable this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396348/are-there-any-browser-layout-engines-which-interpret-sass-natively-without-css)

Comment: how is it a duplicate of that? This is a specififc problem with an SSCE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the sass code, not css. I compiled the sass code and forked your fiddle. Search sass on google. Click on sass in the first page(codepen) to see the compiled css

http://jsfiddle.net/m52vb/

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, #dddddd), color-stop(100%, #cccccc));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#dddddd, #cccccc);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#dddddd, #cccccc);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#dddddd, #cccccc);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#dddddd, #cccccc);
}

#people {
  position: relative;
  margin: 80px auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 480px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: #3b3b3b;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  list-style-type: none;
}
#people li {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 0 40px 0;
  padding: 10px 8px 8px 54px;
  height: 42px;
  border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), inset 0 1px 0 white;
  background: #f6f6f6;
}
#people li img {
  position: absolute;
  top: -16px;
  left: -16px;
  z-index: 10;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
}
#people li h2 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #4b4b4b;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
#people li .info {
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}
#people li .info em {
  margin: 0 18px 0 0;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #5b5b5b;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Just curious, what browsers support SASS, if any? Tried searching but couldn't find definitive answer anywhere.

Comment: Browsers don't natively support sass. There are in time compilers that run on javascript and compile your sass at runtime. Programming languages such as ruby, node etc have the option of sass gems or packages that compile before sending the output.

Answer (score 0):

No idea what it is, but it's not CSS.

Correct CSS would be:

```
html
{
  height: 100%;
}

body
{
  height: 100%;
  //background: #a7d5cd
  background-image(linear-gradient(#dddddd, #cccccc))
}

#people
{
  position: relative;
  margin: 80px auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 480px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: #3b3b3b;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  list-style-type: none;
}

  li
{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 0 40px 0;
    padding: 10px 8px 8px 54px;
    height: 42px;
    border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.06), inset 0 1px 0 #ffffff;
    background: #f6f6f6;
}

 img
{
      position: absolute;
      top: -16px;
      left: -16px;
      z-index: 10;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 4px;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ffffff;
      border-radius: 50%;
}     background: #ffffff;

    h2
{
      margin: 0;
      font-size: 18px;
      line-height: 22px;
      font-weight: 400;
      color: #4b4b4b;
      text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
}


   .info
{
      margin: 0;
      display: block;
}

      em
{
        margin: 0 18px 0 0;
        font-size: 11px;
        line-height: 20px;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: #5b5b5b;
        float: left;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wc3RK/4/).